# android countryPicker from github, bring countries to top

Tags: android, country-codes

I have successfully implemented the AndroidCountryPicker open source project from github. this one: https://github.com/roomorama/AndroidCountryPicker . Now I would like to bring US, HongKong, and Canada to the top of the list. So the user doesn't have to constantly search, and those are going to be the most used.  Anyone know how this would be possible.

Thanks

Comment: You will have to implement something of your own for that but There is something for implementing 
recent search history of the search view.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html

Comment: @XH6user Implementing search history isn't useful, the selection would hopefully only be picked once by the user, and then they wouldn't see it again. I understand I would have to implement something of my own but i was hoping for some direction on where to look or start to get the implementation going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to change the library code to achieve that. The code responsible to load and sort the countries is [this (at 23 Dec 14)](https://github.com/roomorama/AndroidCountryPicker/blob/master/CountryPicker/src/com/countrypicker/CountryPicker.java#L101-L116).

You could ignore those three countries and then add them after sorting the array (supposing you want all the others to appear ordered):

```
Country US, HK, CA;
US = HK = CA = null;
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    Country country = new Country();
    country.setCode(key);
    country.setName(jsonObject.getString(key));
    switch(key) {
        case "US": US = country; break;
        case "HK": HK = country; break;
        case "CA": CA = country; break;
        default: allCountriesList.add(country);
    }
}

Collections.sort(allCountriesList, this);
allCountriesList.add(0, CA);
allCountriesList.add(0, HK);
allCountriesList.add(0, US);
```

If you are using Java 6 or older you will need to replace the switch with if/else's.

**EDIT:** In case anyone wants to change the countries data, it is stored in a big JSON string (encoded in base64) in `res/values/strings_countries.xml`. So that needs to be decoded, changed and then encoded again (something like [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/) or `base64` command will do the trick)

Comment: Wow, this worked exactly how I wanted, thanks alot @Salem! just wanted to add that country US,HK,CA must be initialized or eclipse says error.

Comment: @Yianni You are right. Those vars will be initialized either way, but the compiler has no way to know that. Fixed.

Comment: hey @Salem, any idea how i might be able to add phone number country code next to each country. like US +1, Hong Kong +852..for each one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks